# Generate Multiple Clients for Quarkus

Tags: openapi, quarkus, openapi-generator

tldr; I want to specify openapi documents and create multiple clients.

I am trying to leverage the https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator/ to build clients to multiple systems.

I would like to be able to specify more than one openapi document (ideally from a url not within my repo), to generate clients for each system.  Is there a way to do this?  I am currently able to create a single client, and use it.

Note: tried to tag `quarkiverse`, but lack the 'reputation'.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate multiple openapi spec files in the `openapi` directory under `src/main/`.

*or*

You can dynamically provide open api spec files using `OpenApiSpecInputProvider` interface (see https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator/#generating-files-via-inputstream). The link in the documentation seems to be broken, [here](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator/blob/main/integration-tests/generation-input/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/openapi/generator/codegen/ClassPathPetstoreOpenApiSpecInputProvider.java) you can find an example implementation.